# phit droid algorithm

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I was thinking of trying to make a puzzle solver to games like the phitdroid game on android.

My simple question is:
- Which algorithm could I use?

hope you can help me in the right direction.

Comment: which algorithm should you use for what?

Comment: to find the correct position in the frame

Comment: The key point to your idea is finding a clever algorithm. Why would you even bother building such a thing if you don't intend to come up with the algorithm yourself?

Comment: Because i'm new to this and I just want to learn a lot of different algorithms.. I don't know if it's your intention, but you sound very offending in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phit Droid is kind of like [Pentomino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino). Pentomino can be solved using Knuth's Dancing Links Algorithm (DLX). So i think it's a good starting point.